# Search for the index of an element in A list, and if not found, let the user know

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a basic program that takes an existing list, asks for user input, and searches for the elements of the user's input in the list. I want it to find what index it is at, and print the index. When I enter a value that isn't in the list, I get the error message: "ValueError: 7 is not in list"

How do I stop the program from giving the error message, or to let the user know the value was not in the list?

Edit, adding code:

```
L = [4, 10, 4, 2, 9, 5, 4]
L2 = []
print ("L = ",L)
x = input("Enter an element to search for in the list: ")
x = int(x)

m = L.index(x)
L2.append(m)
print("Found occurences at indexes: ",L2)
```

I'm just trying to find at what index all the occurrences are at, and if there aren't any, print an error message.

Comment: Show us the code you have so far.

Comment: `try: ... catch: ...` Read the python docs :)

Comment: @JoelCornett Well, its `try:... except:...` But that OP has to find out himself.

Comment: @RohitJain: Wow, that was a major brain fart on my part ;)

Comment: @RohitJain: I'm resisting the urge to delete my original comment while simultaneously trying remove my foot from my mouth.

Answer (score 4):

For this you an use try and except to avoid the errors. for example see the code below:

```
>>> list_1=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> input=raw_input("Enter the number:")
Enter the number: 5
>>> try:
...     index=list_1.index(int(input))
...     print "The index is %s" %index
... except ValueError:
...     print "The number is not in the list"
...
The index is 4
```

If you execute it once more time and enter the value not in the list, you will get the message which you have handled using the except.

```
Enter the number:7
The number is not in the list
```

Comment: -1: Bare `except` is bad. If the user enters `a`, he'll get a misleading error message.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Hope will not do this mistake in future.

Comment: @ Myjab -- Do not only try to avoid it in the future, but fix your code.

Comment: I got confusion man. I have got the input inside the try and except block. But you have got it before. At both the ways if user enters 'a' it will rise ValueError. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Then the user gets an error message: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'`. Of course, you can catch that also by surrounding the `raw_input()` call with another `try/except` block.

Comment: This has to do with the scope of the `try/except`: In your first version, there were two possible ways to get a `ValueError`, and your code wasn't differentiating between the two. Additionally, there could have been other errors which your bare `except` would have silently swallowed. Therefore it's important to keep the scope of a `try/except` as small as possible and catch the exceptions as specifically as possible.

Comment: Ya that is what i thought. Since you have told try and except is bad to use, i was thinking for some other ways. Anyway thanks for the comment

Comment: No, no, `try/except` is perfect to use. It's the Pythonic way ("better to ask forgiveness than permission"). It's just not OK to use a bare `except:` because Pokemon exception handling ("Gotta catch them all!") is decidedly unpythonic (and an antipattern in every other language I know).

Answer (score 4):

`.index` is not the way to go, since it finds only the first occurrence of the element. Iterate over the whole list and match individual elements:

```
L2 = [i for i,a in enumerate(L) if a == x]
if L2:
    print "Element found at positions: ", L2
else:
    print "Element is not in the list"
```

`L2` is an empty list or contains **all** indexes where `x` can be found within `L`.

**EDIT**: The "hard" way without `enumerate`:

```
L2 = []
i = -1
while x in L[i+1:]:
    i = L[i+1:].index(x) + i + 1
    L2.append(i)
```

Returns the same results, i.e. empty list if nothing is found.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was the best, but I can't use it since I couldn't explain to my professor how the enumerate works, seeing as how we haven't covered it in class. I'm just going to do it the hard way by finding the index of an element, deleting it, and finding more indexes of the same number. Is there another way to stop the error message if the element isn't in the list?

Comment: You could explain to your professor that you were surreptitiously reading [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) (ZOMG!)

Comment: @user1752061 - See my "hard way" solution. It has to parse list twice.

Answer (score 2):

```
print list1.index(value) if value in list1 else "Not Found"
```

Answer (score 1):

The list comprehension using enumerate is the usual way to do something like this, but it's not that difficult using really basic concepts either.

```
>>> L = [4, 10, 4, 2, 9, 5, 4]
>>> L2 = []
>>> x = 4
>>> for i in range(len(L)):
...     if L[i] == x:
...         L2.append(i)
... 
>>> L2
[0, 2, 6]
```

Comment: Thanks for using basic code, but it still doesn't print an error message to the user if it didn't find the element. What would be the simplest way to add that?

Comment: That part is exactly as in eumiro's answer, so no point to repeat it here.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a simple check against the list (this is just a barebones example - doesn't address multiple occurrences, etc.) This uses Python's `in` operator and is a little more verbose than it needs to be so you can see what is happening:

```
>>> def SimpleCheck(my_list, num):
...   if num in my_list:
...     return l.index(num)
...   else:
...     return 'Nada'
...
>>> l = ['one', 'two', 'three']
>>> SimpleCheck(l, 'three')
2
>>> SimpleCheck(l, 'four')
'Nada'
```